# Where migrations are stored?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have created one new Migration in Visual Studio for my solution and then removed it (just remove files from Visual Studio). But now, when I try to do Update-Database it tries to apply that removed migration. I checked the whole solution and never seen any notification about that removed migration, it's really removed from solution. But package manager try to apply it. Why, where is it stored and how to remove at all?
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you ave correctly recompiled your migration assembly before updating the database?

Comment: As you can see from the PM console output, the `Update-Database` command is trying to apply **automatic** migration, which are generated automatically at *run time* when the model is changed. That's what `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = True` means.

Comment: Other answers are wrong. Ivan is correct. Roll back of migrations described [here] (https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jan/13/Resetting-Entity-Framework-Migrations-to-a-clean-Slate).